# json_normalize を使用してDFを作成したいのですが、keyエラーになってしまう。

Tags: python, python3, pandas

以下のようにJSONファイルを読み込んでDFにしようすると「keyerror」になってしまいます。
なぜでしょうか。

元のJSONファイルは以下です。

```
[
    {
        "creat_at": "2020-04-26T12:55:58+0900",
        "pay_id": "E86F0CD0B346",
        "pay": {
            "a": 1.32,
            "b": [
                0,
                0
            ],
            "c": "xxxx",
            "d": "0709",
            "e": "ssss",
            "f": 290,
            "g": -55,
            "h": 23.3
        },
        "timestamp": "2020-03-16T09:18:39.878Z",
        "updated_at": "2020-04-26T12:55:58+0900"
    },
    {
        "creat_at": "2020-04-26T12:55:58+0900",
        "pay_id": "E86F0CD0B346",
        "pay": {
            "a": 1.32,
            "b": [
                0,
                0
            ],
            "c": "xxxx",
            "d": "0809",
            "e": "ssss",
            "f": 290,
            "g": -55,
            "h": 23.3
        },
        "timestamp": "2020-03-16T09:18:39.878Z",
        "updated_at": "2020-04-26T12:55:58+0900"
    },
・・・
・・・
```

```
json_file = "./export.json"
df0 = pd.read_json(json_file)
df0["pay"].iloc[1]
```

結果

```
{'a': 1.4,
 'b': [29, 0],
 'c': 'xxxx',
 'd': '00070',
 'e': 'ssss',
 'f': 236,
 'g': -95,
 'h': 21.7}
```

上記のデータを以下処理を行いDFにしようとしています。

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
df_items = json_normalize(df0.to_dict("records"), "pay", "pay_id")
df_items.sort_values("item_id")
```

上記の結果から得たい結果は以下ですが、キーエラーになります。なぜでしょうか。

```
|item_id|a  |b   |c   |d   |e   |f  |g  |h   |
|---    |---|--- |----|--- |--- |---|---|--- |
|1      |1.4|29,0|xxxx|0070|ssss|236|-95|21.7|
```

Comment: 最初の`結果`を導ける、実際の`export.json`の内容を提示してください。その中に`"pay"`,`"pay_id"`,`"item_id"`がどのように記述されているのかわからないと検証・助言などは出来ないでしょう。

Comment: export.jsonの内容追加しました。宜しくお願いします。

Answer (score 0):

提示されたプログラムやデータの中には`item_id`というキーの情報は無いし、それを後から設定する処理もありません。

例えば質問記事の`json_normalize()`処理で出来る`df_items`というDataFrameのカラム名は`['0','pay_id']`であり、そこに`item_id`は存在しないので`df_items.sort_values("item_id")`はエラーになります。

個々の処理でどのようなデータが出来ているか、処理のステップ毎に`print()`で確認してみてはどうでしょう？ `print(df0.to_dict("records"))`とか`print(df_items)`とかですね。

なるべくシンプルに対処するなら、以下のようになるでしょう。
`item_id`はリストのインデックス番号をそのまま使います。

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import json_normalize

json_file = "./export.json"
df0 = pd.read_json(json_file)
paylist = df0["pay"]  # 'pay'辞書データのリストを作成

df_items = json_normalize(paylist)  # 'pay'辞書データのリストを normalize
df_items.index.name = 'item_id'     # DataFrameのindexの名前を'item_id'に設定
df_items.sort_values('item_id')

print(df_items)
```

Comment: ご丁寧にありがとうございます。理解できました。